# PHP dom getElementsByTagName length and count error

Tags: php, dom, getelementbyid

I have problem with the code below. `$tables->length` returns `2` but `foreach` only loop once. May I know what is the problem?

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

foreach ($tables as $table) {

}
```

Comment: could you please post XML file as well?

Comment: it is a html file. i am afraid it is long. But there are two tables, but foreach only return the first one. Is this error possible?

Comment: is $tables return array or return only number ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $img =0;
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML("url");
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    foreach ($images as $image) 
    {
        $images= $data->getAttribute('td');
        $img++;

    }
    print_r($images);
?>
```